# FFMPEG: Youtube streaming quality and speed issues

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, streaming, icecast, shoutcast

I am trying to make a reliable stream from my Icecast/Shoutcast servers to Youtube live. The command that I use is:

```
ffmpeg -v verbose -framerate 30 -loop 1 -i /var/image.jpg -re -i http://127.0.0.1:4700/radio -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v 2250k -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 6000k -c:a copy -ab 128k -s 1920x1080 -framerate 30 -g 60 -keyint_min 60 -f flv  rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxx
```

As you can see I am using recommended bitrate for Youtube, insert keyframes every 2 seconds and streaming at 30 frames per second.
The stream is working but after running for some time two thing are happening:

1. FFMPEG `speed` falls from 1x to something like `0.998x`
2. Youtube starts complaining that video stream speed is slow, markes the quality as bad and sometimes video starts buffering.

Why is this happening? CPU load is normal, connectivity is ok (the stream is running on a 1Gg/s dedicated server).

Since in my example above I am streaming a single image as a logo of the stream I also tried to generate a short 30 seconds video with that image and broadcast that video instead of an image, but that did not help as well.

The command I used for conversion:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -loop 1 -i /var/image.jpg -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune stillimage  -b:v 2250k -minrate 2250k -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 6000k -framerate 30 -g 60 -keyint_min 60 -t 30 out4.mp4
```

And broadcast with

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i out4.mp4  -re -i http://127.0.0.1:4700/radio -c:v copy -c:a copy  -framerate 30 -g 60 -keyint_min 60 -f flv  rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxx
```

ffmpeg version is `4.1.1`

Comment: Are you sure that your original stream is really keeping up with the wall-clock? Depending on how it's encoded there are possibilities that it gets heavily skewed. This ultimately leads to buffer under (or overruns if it's too fast) and the player complaining/skipping. Can you try and dump several hours worth of stream to a file and then stream that with ffmpeg? If that works, then it's a strong indication that your original stream timing (sample rate) is off.

Comment: To the OP, how long does it take for YT to complain about stream speed?

Comment: It takes about 1-2 hours

Comment: @TBR you were right, audio stream had timing problems, please make a post and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your original stream is really keeping up with the wall-clock?

Depending on how it's encoded there are possibilities that it gets heavily skewed. This ultimately leads to buffer under (or overruns if it's too fast) and the player complaining/skipping.

Can you try and dump several hours worth of stream to a file and then stream that with FFmpeg? If that works, then it's a strong indication that your original stream timing (sample rate) is off.

Getting the sample rate right is why professional/expensive sound cards use high precision Quartz-Crystal controlled oscillators. Purely virtual processing (e.g. files get encoded into a stream) can easily get skewed, especially inside virtual machines. Also, cheap USB sound cards are often among the worst offenders in terms of frequency accuracy and stability.

FFmpeg might have an option to deal with too slow input. Keywords could be 'padding' or 'missing samples'.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube's error saying "...buffer....." is not a buffer issue on your PC, but simply data you are sending to youtube is too small.

1)note that `[-preset ultrafast]` and `[-preset fast]` does not make big difference.

2) change your ffmpeg comannd for broadcast one. like, `[-b:v 2250k]` to `[-b:v 15000k]`,and set fps to 12→`[-r 12]` option.

I's gonna be.

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i out4.mp4 -re -i http://127.0.0.1:4700/radio -preset fast -r 12 -framerate 30 -g 60 -video_track_timescale 1000 -b:v 15000k -f flv  rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxx
```

I hope this will be good for you !!(^v^)Y